# Access device OS memory from CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone

How can we access device OS memory and store some data in it through CodenameOne.
We need to store some data in OS memory from codenameone app and fetch it from another  nativeapp(as codenameone cannot pass any parameter to native app).

Answer (score 2):

You can call native code from Codename One and all memory in Codename One is native. When you invoke other apps in mobile OS's you can't pass arguments, this is only a feature of Android.

For iOS arguments are usually passed within the URL invoked.